# Copy directoy with SCP

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I'm using the following SCP script to copy a local Windows directory to my Linux machine:

```
scp -r C:\Development\SomeProjectDir myuser@mylinuxmachine:/Development/SomeProject/
```

The first call works like a charm, and all the contents of SomeProjectDir are in the SomeProject folder. However, the second time it doesn't overwrite the contents, instead it creates a SomeProjectDir folder within the SomeProject directory. How to overcome this problem?

(If important: yes, the directory names do NOT match, and I can't make them to match either)

Answer (score 2):

Tell `scp` you want to copy all the contents instead of the top directory:

```
scp -r C:\Development\SomeProjectDir\* myuser@mylinuxmachine:/Development/SomeProject/
                                    ~~
```

Comment: This has the requirement that the directory `/Development/SomeProject/` already exists Is there a way to instruct SCP to create the directory if it does not exist yet?